# Bash. stdout from background piped commands

Tags: bash, background, pipe, stdout

I don't know how to recover the stdout of commands "piped" launched in background. Let's explain. I have this command:

```
iface=$(airmon-ng start wlan0 2> /dev/null | grep monitor)
```

And i want to send all to the background to recover the pid using $!, but when i put & anywhere, the grep stop working and the iface var is empty. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: If you put it in the background, what value do you expect `iface` to have before the command finishes?

Comment: When I execute `airmon-ng start wlan0` it produces a lot of lines as a result. then I want to grep only one line of them which has the text "monitor". The example is a reduced example of what I need. Of course, then is more complex and I use regexps with that line to get the exact name of the interface but is not relevant. The problem here is how to put in the var the line and at the same time execute all in background to get the pid with $! . Thank you for the interest!

Comment: I think I gather what you're doing, but if you're trying to assign the output to a variable, and you're not waiting for the output to finish before you store it in `iface` you could conceivably try to use `iface` before `airmon-ng` has finished.  What value would you expect it to have before `airmon-ng` finishes?  Is this super slow so you need to do it in the background?

Comment: Tha main objective of this is to use a spinner function which draws some chars moving with a "working" while finish the command. I only need to launch the command in the background and after that line use my spinner function which needs only to work the process id i get using $! and after it finish i want to use the results in "iface" never before. Not sure if you understand what I'm trying. Thank you.

Comment: If you aren't married to your own spinner, would `pv` work?  `iface=$(airmon-ng start wlan0 2> /dev/null | grep monitor | pv)` will print a status bar and give you `stdout` in `iface` as you want

Comment: pv is not an option. I need the script working installing as least as possible. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just get status that the script is still running while waiting for the output from `grep` you can use an existing tool like `pv` that will print a progress meter to `stderr` so it won't interfere with your capturing the output.

Failing that, you could write a function that would be slower than the `pv` solution I imagine, but will let you update the spinner after, say, each line like

```
get_monitor() {
    printf ' ' >&2 # to put a first char there to backspace the spinner over
    while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line =~ monitor ]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "$line"
        fi
        update_spinner
    done < <(airmon-ng start wlan0 2>/dev/null)
}

sp_ind=0
sp_chars='/-\|'
sp_num=${#sp_chars}
update_spinner() {
    printf '\b%s' "${sp_chars:sp_ind++%sp_num:1}" >&2
}

iface=$(get_monitor)
```

or you could have your backgrounded command write to a temporary file and get the answer after like

```
airmon-ng start wlan2 2>/dev/null >/tmp/airmon_out &
# your spinner stuff
iface=$(cat /tmp/airmon_out)
```

or perhaps you wouldn't even need it in a variable any more as many things know how to operate on files

Comment: wow... I modified a little bit the spinner but the idea is awesome. Working. you rock dude!